# What time is it? - Fewest number of keystrokes in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Task: display current time to the vim user.

It is *not* a matter of inserting the time into a document, which one can easily do with e.g. !!date. In my question, the user simply wants to know what time it is.

The fewest number of keystrokes seems to involve leaving vim, or to insert the date in a document and deleting it:

1. Call shell, and go back: :!date +enter+
2. Pause vim, type in shell, and go back: ctrl-z date fg
3. Insert into current file, and delete: :r!date dd
4. Type loads of characters and display the date on the command line: :ec strftime("%c")

Surely there must be a shorter command to quickly display current time even without updating the .vmrc file?

Comment: I use `tmux` and for me the answer is 0 keystrokes. :)

Comment: tmux works of course. So does MacOS or Windows or Linux, if you run vim in a window. Another solution is to use a paperclip to fasten a watch to your screen. But going back to the question: if you have only one window with vim and nothing else and want to know what time it is, what's the fewest number of keystrokes?

Comment: Look at a clock on the wall / your phone / your wrist. Zero keystrokes. This isn't CodeGolf.SE.

Comment: No clock on the wall. Phone in the pocket. No wrist watch. I genuinely would like to see the time inside vim. This is not a game. It is a way of saving a few keystrokes for something I do often.

Comment: Belongs on https://vi.stackexchange.com/, but that site doesn't show as an option in the "belongs on another SE site" list

Answer (score 2):

If the motivation for you (as you mention in the comments) is *saving a few keystrokes for something I do often*, the implementation alternatives (as you list them in your question) is irrelevant.

The answer is: You show the time:

- **via a custom mapping / command**, or
- inside the [`:help status-line`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#status-line) or [`:help 'titlestring'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27titlestring%27), where it'll be updated periodically
- echoed whenever you rest (e.g. on the [`:help CursorHold`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorHold) even)

Whatever suits your use case (e.g. showing it only on demand (because you don't want to waste screen real estate or find a periodically updating clock distracting) vs. showing it all the time).

For the implementation, I would recommend `strftime()`, as this is built-in and doesn't require a costly call of an external command. It can be as simple as this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F1> :echo strftime('%c')<CR>
```